# Mail server running sendmail cannot receive incoming mails

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I have a server which is hosting a web site. I want to enable using emails using the domain name (e.g. xxx@mydomain.com), so I configured email service using sendmail and dovecot. I am new to configuring email servers, and currently I met with two strange problems. I am seeking for your kind help:

1. Regarding sending mails to external email addresses defined in /etc/aliases:
   in the /etc/aliases file, I define a group which direct incoming mails to both my local email account and to my external email account, e.g.

   `admin: myname@mydomain.com, myname@mycompany.com`

   When I login to my server and send mails to admin@mydomain.com, both emails can be delivered. However, when I use external mail servers to send (e.g. myname@mycompany.com), only @mydomain.com mail can be delivered, and I got a reject message for @mycompany.com mail:

   `sender address rejected: Access denied`

   I have already enabled FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')
2. I cannot send mails to myname@mydomain.com using web-based emails like gmail, hotmail or yahoo mails. After a few hours (sometimes one day), I got delayed delivery message from web emails. e.g.

   (from gmail)

   ```
   Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:
     myname@mydomain.com

   Message will be retried for 2 more day(s)

   Technical details of temporary failure:
   The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=7720
   [(10) mydomain.com. [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25: Connection refused]
   ```

   I have already configured firewalls to allow needed ports (e.g 25, 143, 110). And I can the mails sent from @mycompany.com can be delivered.

   I suspect the web mail servers may require extra verification. What other configurations should I do to enable my mail server receive external mails?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: 0) Which OS/Distribution do you use? [Some tests are OS/Distribution dependent] 1) Does you sendmail listen only on loopback interface?  What is reported by `nestat -ant | grep :25`

Comment: 0) I use Centos 6.3 x64. 1) Send mail is listening to all (or else it cannot receive mails sent from @mycompany.com) 2) port 25 is on. I use telnet to test. Iptables is modified to allow port 25, too.